# child menus are getting hide behind parent div due to overflow hidden property in css

Tags: html, css

am trying to create scroll-able menu with child menu's ,and for scrolling purpose i need to use overflow:hidden property and due to this property my child menu's are getting hide behind the parent div to which i have seted overflow:hidden property,so i want to make these child menu's visible,here  my html looks like

```
<div id="content" class="defaults">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul id="thumbs" class="static content">
                    <li class="static dynamic-children item">
                        <a><span><span>Contact Us</span></span></a>
                        <ul style="" class="dynamic">
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span>Link1</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span>Link2</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link3</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="static item">
                        <a><span><span>About Us1</span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="static item">
                        <a><span><span>About Us2</span></span></a>
                        <ul class="dynamic">
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link1</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link2</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link3</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="static item">
                        <a><span><span>About Us3</span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="static item">
                        <a><span><span>About Us4</span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="static item">
                        <a><span><span>About Us</span></span></a>
                        <ul class="dynamic">
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link1</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link2</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dynamic item">
                                <a><span><span>Link3</span></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is my css

```
  .wrapper
    {
        width: 817px;
        background: rgb(205, 205, 245);
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: 66px;
        margin-right: 43px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: -24px;
}
    .content
    {
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-right: 6px;    
    }




    .item
    {
        display: inline-block;
        /* background: #0072c6;*/
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: #dcecd9;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-right: 1px;
    }
```

Comment: Post your html code here. People can not run screenshots.

Comment: actually am doing that in share-point and there is no any HTML structure am creating this with share-point's master page internal code,with the browser only i can share the html structure

Comment: Just right click on html code snippet shown code inspector and select `copy inner html`.

Comment: actually i simplified  this structure because there are many classes are assigned to thes li and Ul internaly in sharepoint